# How to connect converse.js with openfire?

Tags: apache, openfire, converse.js

I have installed openfire as xmmp converse.js as server and chat client and OS Windows 8.I Probe openfire with pidgin and works. I can not connect converse.js with openfire, and I have done the following:
-I have enabled HTTP binding in openfire

-I modify the index of converse.js by:

```
require(['converse'], function (converse) {
 converse.initialize({
 auto_list_rooms: false,
 auto_subscribe: false,
 bosh_service_url: 'http://localhost:7070/http-bind/',
 hide_muc_server: false,
 i18n: locales.en, // Refer to ./locale/locales.js to see which locales are supported
 prebind: false,
 show_controlbox_by_default: true,
 roster_groups: true
 });
  });
```

-I went to the firewall and enable the ports necessary for the connection (5222, 5229, 7070 and 7443)

-I insert in openfire the xmpp.httpbind.worker.threads and xmpp.client.processing.threads properties with value 16

-I modify apache httpd.conf: I enable LoadModule proxy_http_module and LoadModule proxy_module and I added:

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass / http-bind http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/

ProxyPassReverse / http-bind http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/

When I log in with a openfire's user  the window stays on connecting.

Please if anyone has a guide on how to connect with openfire converse.js me would be helpful.

Thanks and sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

Your bosh_service_url should actually be 'http://localhost/http-bind/' since you are running a proxy server.  I am assuming that your apache server is running on the standard port 80. Though if you just turn apache off you should be able to connect directly to openfire with your current converse.js configuration.